# ReactJS - Change my loading to false after all data is entered in the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to change my `state.loading` to `false` after all data is entered in the state.

I want to create a web workflow as follows:

1. `state` created with `loading` condition set to true
2. I want to take 3 JSON files with the `axios` and save them into a `state`.
3. If all three data have been successfully saved into a `state`, then change `state.loading` to `false`

But what I got was that `state.loading` was declared `false` before all of the data was called.

This is the code look like:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jobs    : [],
      category: [],
      location: [],
      loading : true
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    //get any jobs available
    axios.get('/thisjob/all/all').then(({data}) => this.setState({
      jobs: [...data.jobs]
    }));
    //get any categories available
    axios.get('/thiscategory').then(({data}) => this.setState({
      category: [...data.category]
    }));
    //get any locations available
    axios.get('/thislocation').then(({data}) => this.setState({
      location: [...data.location]
    }));
    this.setState({
      loading: false
    })
  }
```

And this is the screenshot that I found in while `console.log()`-ing state in `render()`
[image: state.loading has been declared as false before all data loaded]

I have tried various ways from using the if statement to trying to save it on another lifecycle method, but the results are still not like the workflow I requested.

Comment: componentWillMount is a wrong place to fetch api data , use componentDidMount

Comment: I already update it, but still have same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use async await methods or promise all.
Once all the promy resolved you setState to loading false.
`await Promise.all([someCall(), anotherCall()]);`
And just like the someone pointed out, do the fetch in componentDidMount and add a async

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const res = await axios.get('/thisjob/all/all');
    const {ip} = await res.json(); // do other logic
    const res1 = await axios.get('/thiscategory');
    const {other} = await res1.json(); // do other logic
    const res2 = await axios.get('/thislocation');
    const {other2} = await res2.json(); // do other logic
    await this.setStateAsync({loading: false})
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, you might 'want to'

Comment: It works now. by applying `async` and `await` in my method